# How to use variable in xpath xslt?

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, xpath

i have the following xml properties file as input,

```
<Service>
    <Provider>
        <TEST1>http://example1.com</TEST1>
        <TEST2>http://example2.com</TEST2>
        <TEST3>http://example3.com</TEST3>
    </Provider>
</Service>
```

in my xslt, based on the incoming request host name (example: https://test2service.example.com) ; using contains function i am saving environment value to a variable.

```
<xsl:variable name="Environment">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($ConsumerHost, 'test1')">
                    <xsl:text>TEST1</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($ConsumerHost, 'test2')">
                    <xsl:text>TEST2</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when> ..........
```

Now based on the environment variable value, i have to choose the backend server. below code is not working. Please suggest.

```
<xsl:variable name="HOST" select="//Provider/($Environment)/text()" />
```

Any other solutions are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this expression instead...

```
<xsl:variable name="HOST" select="//Provider/*[local-name() = $Environment]/text()" />
```

Comment: The expression should produce a result. See http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYjr as an example. If it is not getting any output for you, you may need to expand your answer to show more details. Possibly issues may be how the variable `ConsumerHost` is set, or possibly namespace issues.